# Unity: How to remove inactive gameObject from List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, gameobject

I made a List of gameObjects that are currently in my box collider and it works. However, when I set a gameobject inactive,

```
gameObject.SetActive(false); // To Eliminate Enemy
```

the gameObject remains in the List without being removed. How do I remove the gameObject from a List in the OnTriggerEnter function from another class?

PlayerLifeClass:

```
     private List<GameObject> ObjectsInRange = new List<GameObject>();
        public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
        {
            if (collider.tag != "Player" && collider.tag == "Zombie")
            {
                ObjectsInRange.Add(collider.gameObject);
                damage = ObjectsInRange.Count; //amount of zombies inside collider
               //***Over here***

                zombie.DamagePlayer(damage);
                Debug.Log(damage);
            }
        }
        public void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
        {
            if (collider.tag != "Player" && collider.tag == "Zombie")
            {
                //Probably you'll have to calculate which object it is
                ObjectsInRange.Remove(collider.gameObject);
                Debug.Log(ObjectsInRange);
            }
        }
```

---

```
ZombieClass:

    public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int currentHealth;
        private Player player;
        private PlayerLifeCollider playerCollider;
    
        public void Damage(int damageAmount)
        {
            //subtract damage amount when Damage function is called
            currentHealth -= damageAmount;
    
            //Check if health has fallen below zero
            if (currentHealth <= 0)
            {
                //if health has fallen below zero, deactivate it 
                gameObject.SetActive(false); //***Over here***
     
            }

   public void DamagePlayer(int damage)
    {
         player.Life(damage);
      }
   }
```

Comment: why not just do `Destroy(gameObject);`

Comment: Would Destroy(gameObject) remove it from the List? I was going to, but then I was told SetActive(false) is better for performance.

Comment: I feel that it would just make the gameObject a null rather then remove it from the List.

Comment: I couldnt understand your question i guess, so you want to remove the gameobject from the ObjectsInRange list from inside the Damage() function in the Zombie class?

Comment: Yes. As I believe the issues with alternatives is that if you call List.Remove after it has been inactivated, it will not work.

Comment: then checkout my solution and let me know if it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you want, Something like this would do,

**PlayerLife Class**

```
public static List<GameObject> ObjectsInRange = new List<GameObject>();
```

**Zombie Class**

```
public void Damage(int damageAmount)
    {
        //subtract damage amount when Damage function is called
        currentHealth -= damageAmount;

        //Check if health has fallen below zero
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            //if health has fallen below zero, deactivate it
            PlayerLife.ObjectsInRange.Remove(gameObject); 
            gameObject.SetActive(false); //***Over here***
            //You can also do a Destroy(gameObject) if you'd like;

        }
    }
```

Comment: The static functionally works! However, it forces me to change everything to static. Is there a way to do the one liner without statics?

Comment: @BenSmith you can use singletons, if you dont want to set all variables as static.  see my answer below.

Comment: @BenSmith What does it force you to change? you can access static variables anywhere inside and outside a class.

Answer (score 2):

You have more ways, i'll show you an easy.

**Modificate** your Zombie Class:

```
public bool Damage(int damageAmount)
{
    currentHealth -= damageAmount;
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false); //***Over here***
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

and PlayerLifeClass:

```
if (collider.tag != "Player" && collider.tag == "Zombie"){
    ObjectsInRange.Add(collider.gameObject);
    damage = ObjectsInRange.Count; //amount of zombies inside collider
    if(collider.GetComponent<Zombie>().Damage(damage)){
        // if zombie dead, remove him.
        ObjectsInRange.Remove(collider.gameObject);
    }
    Debug.Log(damage);
}
```

**Or somithing like that**, but it not good choice, i think.

```
void Start(){
   playerLifeClass = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player")>GetComponent<PlayerLifeClass>();
}
public bool Damage(int damageAmount)
{
    currentHealth -= damageAmount;
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
    //if health has fallen below zero, deactivate it 
       gameObject.SetActive(false); //***Over here***
       playerLifeClass.RemoveZombie(gameObject);
    }
}
```

And in PlayerLifeClass add new Method:

```
public void RemoveZombie(GameObject zomb){
   ObjectsInRange.Remove(zomb);
}
```

**Or use Singletons.** Add new variable to PlayerLifeClass:

```
...
public static PlayerLifeClass instance;
public List<GameObject> ObjectsInRange = new List<GameObject>();
...

void Start(){
    instance = this;
    ...
}
```

And Use it in Zombie.cs:

```
 if (currentHealth <= 0){
    gameObject.SetActive(false); //***Over here***
    PlayerLifeClass.instance.ObjectsInRange.Remove(gameObject);
 }
```

Comment: Ok, and ps, I tried the first two and it didn't work. I either got a NullReferenceException or when the zombies got inactivated the same problem occurred, whereas the damage didn't go back to zero.

Comment: @BenSmith yes, maybe my examples not 100% solution, and perhaps they have some errors, but they should give you some idea. good luck)

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException when I declare  zombie.DamagePlayer(damage)as a non-static. Do you know how to fix it? I feel it's just knowing the basics.

Comment: your zombie variable not initialized. try it: if(collider.GetComponent<Zombie>()!=null){ zombie =  collider.GetComponent<Zombie>(); zombie.DamagePlayer(damage); }}